# Creating multiple node references

Tags: nodes

I have the following content types - Efforts, Objectives, Groups and the user.

Efforts and Objectives can be shared by both users and groups. A user/group can have multiple objectives and efforts and can also share the same objectives/efforts.

Is it possible by using node references ? or Is there any other way where I can implement this functionality in drupal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you have to use node reference
I think you need a node reference in efforts and objectives to select users or group so you need a node reference to a view (you can reference to a view it should not be node)

the same user/Group make a view reference to objects and efforts

If you have any problem make a comment

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty new to drupal, I don't actually get it but How do I create a Views Reference ? is it a module that I can install ?

Comment: Someone also suggested me to use Organic Groups. Is that possible ? I don't quite understand how organic groups can be used in this context. In my case, a effort can be independent or can be shared by a group or can be shared by a user or can be both. Its the same with objective too! I don't know how to establish that relationship in Drupal

Comment: I don't Know Organic group but i think its more complex but about reference to a view it does not need any modules you will find it below your content (as you can choose a content type you will find below the list of content type list of all view but you have to choose  in a view reference view not page or block  (you will find reference view inside view after make the default) I hope you get it any comment I will try to help you